# What is the thinnest possible depth of any given material required to display an image?

Tags: electrical-engineering, telecommunication

I am interested in creating a screen to display moving images (similar to moving desktop background), however I am looking for the thinnest possible material available i can use as the screen to display the image.

Ideally working in the same way as a laptop screen however much thinner (E.g only using the components necessary to display the image, no housing).  The material can be any at this stage, such as plasma, LCD, LED, etc.

My intention is to create something that works in a similar way to wallpaper, where it can be applied directly to a wall, and for it to be connected wirelessly to a transmitter in order for it to display a moving image.

Any answers would be much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Do you need the display to emit light (active) or just reflect ambient light (passive)? [OLED](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLED) and [e-paper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_paper) are probably the thinnest active and passive display technologies, respectively.

Comment: **Why** do you need an ultrathin display?  The support electronics will be much thicker,  and keeping a thin sheet flat in the presence of everyday acoustics is quite difficult.    BTW, if you wanted a projection system, the answer, quite seriously, is one molecule thick.

Comment: @DaveTweed my apologies for lack of knowledge in regard to various displays, I would like the display to show a moving image on a loop, such as fish swimming.  I am a student and interested in new technologies so I am looking to do something which has not been done before, this being applying the screen to a wall in a similar way to wallpaper, to cover large areas, eg 2 walls of a bedroom. I will look into these technologies, what do you think would be most suitable ?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft as described above my intention is to create a very thin screen, which can be applied to a wall. much more along the lines of electronic wallpaper rather than wall mounted tv.  As it will be secured to a room I am not worried about it flexing. I am wondering how many layers thick does the screen have to be to successfully display a moving image without it being too faint ?

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume that you are using OLEDs (organic light emitting diodes) which can emit a photon when charged with an electron. You could build a single molecule pixel (just nip down to the corner store and pick up an electron microscope with atomic manipulator). However the Real challenge is the wiring and insulation. the real question is how are you going to separate your pixels electrically while powering and addressing them. by the time you figured out how to do the wiring, the lights are only a heat dissipation issue.

Current thinking on OLED containers is dual transparent conductive plates sandwiching your organics. since both glass and plastic can be produced a thickness under 1mm there is no reason other than heat dissipation to expect thickness to be much greater than 3mm. On the other hand heat dissipation is a big issue and proportional to the size of the display.